# Ringneck's wing feathers aren't growing back after clipping

Tags: diet, birds, injury

Acquaintance of mine gave me a young ringneck (about 3 years old) saying that
ever since her partner clipped its wing feathers, it won't grow back.
My question is, how is this possible?
She said the wings were clipped 7 months ago and didn't grow back ever since.
Is it possible that her partner somehow injured the bird in such
a way that the feathers won't grow anymore? Is there any kind of nutrition I should try? I'd love to see the bird fly.

From the bird's appearance I suspect the bird is malnutritioned hence
doesn't have enough nutrients to grow nice long feathers. I started the bird on plenty of vitamins. Leafy vegs, bananas, carrots, apples and seeds.

I hope to see dramatic improvement with time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a feather is pulled out, it takes 3 to 6 months for it to fully regrow. If it takes longer then it is due to his condition of life.
To accelerate the growth of its feathers you must improve its condition of life. I don't know the conditions under which you live with your bird, but here are the different points to which you must pay attention and which will accelerate its growth of feathers:

- Food: The bird should have a varied diet with fresh food every day (I read that you give it vegetables and fruit,... and this is therefore a very good thing). The bird must have a daily intake of fruit (apple, banana, orange, grapes, cherry, strawberry, pear, ...) and vegetables (carrot, zucchini, beans, spinach, tomato, ...). But he must also have dry food (seeds, cereals, millet,….). Also it is important to add legumes (chickpeas, lentils, etc.) and a little rice or paste from time to time. You can also give it eggs, it helps to regrow feathers.
- Light: It is important for your bird to have a weekly UV dose! Either you can put it in an outdoor aviary where it will have direct access to the sun but if you don't have an aviary or the opportunity to put it outside you can buy UV lamps for birds which are sold in pet stores or you can easily find it on the internet.
- Humidity: This last point is very important for good feather health and normal feather growth. You will need to moisten your bird regularly with a sprayer or you can also wash with him if he is confident enough with you. Otherwise you can also give him a small bathtub (easily available from pet stores) with a little lukewarm water.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I've been giving the bird scrambled eggs with greens, various seeds, apples, pieces of carrot, bananas and treats for budgies as well. The bird seems to like those. So far the ringneck eats well. I do have opportunity to take him out on sunlight so no problem there. Speaking of the last point. I'll likely have to spray him because even though he doesn't fear my finger but he fears me. Weird I know. The ringneck is only partly tamed unlike my budgie.

Answer (score 2):

Ringneck parakeets molt just once a year. Clipped feathers are replaced like any others, at the next molt. Since your bird's feathers were clipped seven months ago, there is nothing to worry about yet. If the feathers do not grow back a year after they were clipped, consult an avian veterinarian.

The diet you are giving your bird is varied and should be fun for it. Be sure to provide a solid, balanced foundation, too--either one of the several pellet diets that are available (which some birds like but others refuse) or a fortified diet such as Lafeber's nutriberries. That will ensure that your bird's new feathers grow in strong.

You might also try giving your ringneck whole peanuts in the shell (NOT roasted or salted). They love whole peanuts. Peanuts are part treat and part toy. I've seen them destroy whole sacks of peanuts in India. Some peanuts might help make your bird more tame.

It sounds like you're a good bird parent. Be patient and the feathers should come in on the next molt. Until then, love and peanuts.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice, Tom. The bird is getting peanuts from day 1 as it comes with the seeds I've been giving him. And yeah, the bird loves them. The bird is already getting better as I can tell its mood has improved and he has became louder as well. I'll be so happy to see his wing feathers growing !

Comment: It could've been 7 months since the wing feathers were clipped but I think my acquintance just estimated as she didn't seem very clear about this. So there's good chance that it happened not 7 but only 6 months ago which means I need to be all the more patient.